# Unable to Connect to Internet after signing the apk

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have built an Android Application using **Phonegap and Jquery Mobile.** Everything works fine until **I sign the apk file**. I'm able to access the internet being sand establish a connection with my backend server, **But When I sign the apk, I'm not able to contact my backend server.** The connection is not established with the server. I have declared **internet, network state permissions in the manifest file** and specified the **access origin as well in the config.xml** file. But stil I'm not able to connect to the server.
**This problem appears only after signing the app**. I'm able to access the internet but not able to send the request back to the server.

Comment: We need more information as you can guess...

Comment: Are you using proguard and are you getting proguard errors during the build? I would check my log for missing classes.

Comment: no i'm not using proguard.

Comment: I have provided more info.

Comment: are you using https?

Comment: Hi @3Esofttech did you solve your problem, I have the same issue :(

Comment: The same problem. I use only jQuery getJSON